# How can I black & white camera in unity 2019.1.9?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want make a filter camera for unity that black & white in unity 2019.1.9
How can I make it?
That can change it to RGB and black and white every time

Comment: it is best to at least detail and demonstrates what you have tried so far.

Comment: Surely, you're using [tag:c#], not [tag:unityscript].

Answer (score 6):

You can achieve this using [Post Processing Color Grading](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PostProcessing-ColorGrading.html?_ga=2.94732316.142065910.1575433516-1609044236.1573615755)

[image]

#### Steps:

1. Follow the [installation steps.](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.postprocessing@2.1/manual/Installation.html)
2. Add Post-Processing Layer and the Post-Processing Volume as per [instructions](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.postprocessing@2.1/manual/Quick-start.html)
3. Add a [color grading effect](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PostProcessing-ColorGrading.html)
4. Turn saturation all the way down to -100

#### Post Processing Component:

[image]

Comment: It's worth noting that the process is different for the SRP pipelines than it is for the builtin-in render pipeline.